# total variation distance and coupling

Tags: statistics, markov-chains, total-variation, coupling

How can we show that $||\gamma M- \beta M||_{TV}\leq||\gamma -\beta||_{TV}$ (total variation distance) for a transition matrix of a markov chain $M$ ?

$\gamma, \beta$ are two distributions on the state space $S$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

\begin{align}
\|\gamma M- \beta M\|_{\text{TV}}&=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{s\in S}\left|(\gamma M)(s)-(\beta M)(s)\right|\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{s\in S}\left|\sum_{s'\in S}(\gamma(s')-\beta(s')) M(s',s)\right|\\
&\le\frac{1}{2}\sum_{s'\in S}\left|\gamma(s')-\beta(s')\right|\sum_{s\in S}M(s',s) \\
&=\|\gamma - \beta\|_{\text{TV}}.
\end{align}